# read file and writing file in C

Tags: c

I have some questions ,  I want to read input .txt file paramaters and writing output.txt .I  can find just one line the ,how I can find all line the same for this question  ?and when input.txt file paramater delete ,will delete output.file the characters .

input.txt file details

```
write: 3 a 4 b 1 \n 2 d
delete: 1 a 2 b
```

output.txt will apply first paramater  will  be result

```
aaa bbbb 

dd
```

output.txt will apply second paramater be  result

```
aa bb

dd
```

thanks for your answer in advance

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main(void)
    {
    FILE *read, *write;     /* files pointers  */
    char *source_file = "input.txt";
    char *dest_file=  "output.txt";
    int count;
    char ch;
    char choose []="write";
    int z=0;
    if( (read=fopen(source_file, "r")) == NULL ) /* files check ? */
     {
     printf("%s didnt' open .\n", source_file);
     exit(1);
     }
   if( (write=fopen(dest_file, "w")) == NULL )
    {
    printf("%s didnt. open \n", source_file);
    exit(2);
    }
    fscanf(read,"%s%d%c",&choose,&count,&ch);
    while( ( ch = fgetc(read) ) != EOF )
   {
      printf("%d%c",count,ch);
      z=0;
      for (; z<count; z++)
      {
          fprintf(write,"%c",ch);
          printf("\n");
      }
      fprintf(write," ");
      fscanf(read,"%d%c",&count,&ch);
      printf("\n");
   }
   fclose(read);    /* files close */
  fclose(write);
  printf("%s > %s\n",source_file, dest_file);
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: 0) `1 \n` --> `2 \n` 1)`char choose []="write";` small for `delete`. 2) `%s%d%c"` --> `" %[^:]:%d %c"` but can't read `\n` ( two character)

Comment: Thank you for your response ,When I tried I saw the mistake , How I can solve the problem  ?

Comment: The proposal, I think that any good(and easy) when treated after you apply the delete command to the write command. E.g `write: 3 a 4 b 1 \n 2 d
delete: 1 a 2 b` ==> update write comand to `write: 2 a 2 b 1 \n 2 d`

Answer (score 0):

try this(some check is omitted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct task {
    int id;
    char ch;
    int times;
    struct task *next;
} Task;

typedef struct task_list {
    Task *head;
    Task *tail;
} TaskList;

typedef enum mode { NOP, WRITE, DELETE } Mode;

Task *new_task(int id, int freq, char aChar);
void add_taskList(TaskList *list, Task *task);
void update_taskList(TaskList *list, Task *task);
void drop_taskList(TaskList *list);
void fout_taskList(FILE *fp, TaskList *list);

int main(void) {
    char line[1024];
    char command[16];
    TaskList list = { NULL, NULL};
    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0;

    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)){
        int len, pos = 0;
        Mode mode = NOP;

        sscanf(line, " %15[^:]:%n", command, &len);
        pos += len;

        if(!strcmp(command, "write"))
            mode = WRITE;
        else if(!strcmp(command, "delete"))
            mode = DELETE;
        else
            continue;//ignore

        int freq = 0;
        char aChar;
        while(2 == sscanf(line + pos, "%d %c%n", &freq, &aChar, &len)){
            if(aChar == '\\'){
                char esc_char = line[pos + len];
                len += 1;
                switch(esc_char){
                case 'n':
                    aChar = '\n';
                    break;
                case 't':
                    aChar = '\t';
                    break;
                case ' ':
                    aChar = ' ';
                    break;
                }
            }
            Task *task = new_task(++i, freq, aChar);
            if(mode == WRITE)
                add_taskList(&list, task);
            else //if(mode == DELETE)
                update_taskList(&list, task);

            pos += len;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    fout_taskList(fp, &list);
    fclose(fp);

    drop_taskList(&list);
    return 0;
}

Task *new_task(int id, int freq, char aChar){
    Task *new_task = malloc(sizeof(*new_task));

    if(new_task){
        new_task->id    = id;
        new_task->times = freq;
        new_task->ch    = aChar;
    }
    return new_task;
}

void add_taskList(TaskList *list, Task *task){
    if(list->head){
        list->tail = list->tail->next = task;
    } else {
        list->head = list->tail = task;
    }
}
void update_taskList(TaskList *list, Task *task){
    Task *p = list->head;
    while(p){
        if(p->ch == task->ch){
            p->times -= task->times;//if(p->times < 0) p->times = 0;
            if(task->id > 0){//Execute only the first found element
                break;
            }
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
}
void drop_taskList(TaskList *list){
    Task *p = list->head;
    while(p){
        Task *tmp = p->next;
        free(p);
        p = tmp;
    }
    list->head = list->tail = NULL;
}
void fout_taskList(FILE *fp, TaskList *list){
    char prev = '\n';
    Task *p = list->head;
    while(p){
        for(int i = 0; i < p->times; ++i){
            fputc(prev = p->ch, fp);
        }
        if(prev != '\n')
            fputc(' ', fp);
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```